# Validacion de datos en datatable

Tags: ajax, datatables

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente inconveniente en un botón necesito hacer validaciones sobre un datatable, hago validaciones para el formulario y funciona pero no se porque no me funciona la validacion para los mensajes "Producto existente..." va a la url  y luego "Primero debe seleccionar productos simples....." debe contar las filas del datatable #resultados1 si es 0 da el mensaje. Muchas gracias
adjunto script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#generarcompuesto').click(function(){




 cadena="nproductc=" + $('#nproductc').val() +

          "&idarea=" + $('#idarea').val(); +

          "&cantidadpc=" + $('#cantidadpc').val(); +

          "&idcategoria=" + $('#idcategoria').val(); +


          "&idestino=" + $('#idestino').val();



          $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"ajax/comp_prodc.php",
            data:cadena,
            success:function(r){

              if($('#nproductc').val()==""){
        alertify.alert('Atención',"Debes agregar el nombre del producto");
        return false;
      }else if($('#cantidadpc').val()==""){
        alertify.alert('Atención',"Debes agregar una cantidad");
        return false;
         }else if($('#cantidadpc').val() == 0){
        alertify.alert('Atención',"Debes agregar una cantidad valida");
        return false;
      }else if($('#idcategoria').val()==""){
        alertify.alert('Atención',"Debes seleccionar  categoria");
        return false;
      }else if($('#idestino').val()==""){
        alertify.alert('Atención',"Debes agregar el destinatario");
        return false;
      }

              else if(r == '1'){
                 alertify.alert('Atención',"Este producto ya existe, prueba con otro nombre ");
                 return false;


              }else if($('#resultados1').rows().count()==0){
                 alertify.alert('Atención',"Primero debe seleccionar productos simples, para generar uno compuesto");
                 return false;



              }else{
                alertify.alert('Atención',"Producto compuesto generado");
              }


            }
          });
    });
  });
</script>


// la url de validacion es comp_prodc.php y la validacion es

    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);

require_once "../data/conexion.php";

$id_area = $_POST['idarea'];

$nproductc = $_POST['nproductc'];

$cantidadpc = $_POST['cantidadpc'];

$idcategoria = $_POST['idcategoria'];

$fechaout = $_POST['fechaout'];

$fechaout = date_create($fechaout);
$fechaout = $fechaout->format('Y-m-d H:i');

$sentencia6 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM  producto_comp where nombre = '$nproductc' and id_area = '$id_area' ");
if (mysqli_num_rows($sentencia6) > 0) {

    echo '1';
}

?>
```

Comment: Perdon, aclaro    El mensaje 'Atención',"Este producto ya existe,......." es el que espera un echo '1' de la pagina comp_prodc.php  y el mensaje 'Atención',"Primero debe seleccionar productos simples,....." es el que debe contar las filas del datatable #resultados1 que si es 0 muestra el mensaje ...no se como debo escribirlo ...Gracias